# Does the property spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads in Spark Yarn configuration affect the total running time?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

In the spark documentation the property `spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads` is explained [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) as

> The maximum number of
>   threads to use in the YARN Application Master for launching executor
>   containers.

Does it mean that only a maximum of 25 executors will be running in parallel?

Is it possible to increase the performance by configuring this property?